# Concept of $location

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand this. In my local I am trying to develop a website. In that website links are working in app but when I try to F5 or copy that link and paste it to browser I am getting 404 Page Not Found error. I google it and found that this related to parsing URLs but cant figure out how to do this. Here is my code:

Javascript

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('baba', {
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "baba.html"
    })
    .state('icerik', {
        url: "/icerik/:ad",
        templateUrl: "icerik.html",
        controller: "mmgCtrl",
    })
    .state('oku', {
        url: "/oku/:serix/:klasor",
        templateUrl: "oku.html",
        controller: "nbgCtrl"
    })
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

.controller('indexCtrl', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.yonlen = $location.path();
})
```

I have two routes. `/icerik` and `/oku`. So I think I should do if statement to which url going to which scopes.

index.html

```
<div ng-repeat="manga in mangas">

<a ng-href="{{yonlen}}></a>

</div>
```

Comment: What URLs did you tried ?

Comment: Are you using any kind of routing pattern like ngRoute or ui.router?

Comment: @Farzad YZ Yes I am using `ui-router` and updating my question.

Comment: The issue here is with html5Mode.  Have you read the article that ui-router has on this issue? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: @Claies Yes this is solve my issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, this uses `pushState`.

When you change the state of the page with JavaScript, you should change the URL to one which would cause the server to generate the page in *that state*.

That would mean that [if the JavaScript failed for any reason](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html), the content [would still load correctly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and that if someone followed a deep link, they would *directly* (and thus quickly) load the content they were actually concerned with.

For example:

- The visitor arrives on the homepage
- The server delivers the homepage (plus all the angular code)
- They click the "blog" link
- You load blog content and put it on the page (with JS)
- You change the URL to `/blog/` (still with JS) without loading a fresh page from the server

But then:

- The visitor arrives on the blog
- The server delivers the blog page (plus all the angular code)

You're doing the *change the URL* but but haven't done the *put the right content at that URL* bit. That requires server side work.